# How to make WooCommerce checkout page load faster?

Tags: wordpress, caching, woocommerce, pagespeed

How to make WooCommerce checkout page load faster?
It loads for like 5-7 seconds in my fully cached Wordpress website (full W3 Total Cash). This is waay too long and i need to speed it up.
But i cant fugure out how to do it.

I saw people use Varnish Cache to speed the checkout page up, but i am not sure where to put it - in which file?

[the varnish cache that i saw](https://www.serveu.net/web-design-tips/how-to-optimize-varnish-cache-for-woocommerce.html#code)

I can give you a link, if you want, but on PM pls. 
Thanks.

Comment: This question is likely to only invite opinion and is not directly code related, please consider closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Even with Varnish, your checkout page still can't load faster because caching checkout page is not recommended. If you caching your checkout page or cart page with varnish, users will can't make any change to their cart.

This problem is more related to your hosting/server performance.

Answer (score 0):

Like @anh-tuan already suggested, caching won't help you because you'd never want to cache a checkout page anyway since by its very nature a checkout page is dynamic.

Before looking at your hosting options, I'd suggest you first take a good look at your plugins and your theme functions. The problem may lie there.

Comment: i have zero plugins - only woocommerce, W3 Total Cache and Yoast SEO.
i dont want the user to make changes in checkout - i need just for it to be faster.

So i couldnt figure out this Varnish - i am 100% sure that others cant figure it out too.
Its not so simple ...
So i ask kindly for help .....
Thanks in advance